# How to save fetched image from json to external storage in phonegap for android?

Tags: android, jquery, json, eclipse, cordova

Hello I'm developing a project in which I need to fetch image from JSON link.
now what I want is, that image wil be save first time in external storage in my android phone and after that image will fetched from my external storage not from json file. I want my app to give offline support if data connection is not there.
I'm able to load image but don't know how to save it on external storage in my mobile device. I'using Phonegap with Eclipse.

> This is My Json file

```
  [ 
    {
     "image":"timthumb.php?src=newsimages\/14351244224.jpg&w=125&h=90",  "news_id":"411"`,"news_title":"JEE (\u090f\)","added_date":"2015-06-24"},
{"image":"timthumb.php?src=newsimages\/2015\/06\/143434188770.jpg&w=125&h=90","news_id":"404","news_title":"\u092e\\u0947 ","added_date":"2015-06-15"}
```

This is My Code that access Image and other data from Json :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    function fetchfromJsonfile() { 
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "URL_here,
     cache: false,
     beforeSend: function() {
     $('#res2').html('loading please wait...');
     },
     success: function(jsondata) {  
    var i=1;
    $.each(jsondata, function(idx, obj) {   
    var str = '';
    var img='';
    var latestNews='';
    var date='';

    date += obj.added_date;
    str += obj.news_title;
    img += "<img src='URL"+obj.image+"'/>";
    $('#image'+i).html(img);


            $('#latestNews'+i).html(str);
            $('#date'+i).html(date);
            $('#res2').html(' ');
            $('#button').hide();

       i++;

       });
        }
       });
      }
```

```
      <div>
        <h3 id="image1"></h3>
            <strong id="latestNews1">Loding...</strong>
           <div class="decoration"></div>                
          <h3 id="image2"></h3>
          <strong id="latestNews2">Loding...</strong>

            <em id="date2"></em>


        <div class="decoration"></div>                
          <h3 id="image3"></h3>
          <strong id="latestNews3">Loding...</strong>

            <em id="date3"></em>

      <div class="decoration"></div> 
         <h3 id="image4"></h3>
         <strong id="latestNews4">Loding...</strong>
            <em id="date4"></em>


        <div class="decoration"></div>
          <h3 id="image5"></h3>
           <strong id="latestNews5">Loding...</strong>
            <em id="date5"></em>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) for adding file permissions in your application. You need to add some plugins which information you can get from above link I have mentioned.

Basically when you download file it gets saved in your mobile gallery for Android.

Here is Code for downloading file:

```
var file_url = 'http://aws_s3_or_any_other_url';
var filePath = 'local/path/to/your/file';
var downloadFile = new FileTransfer();
var encoded_url = encodeURI(url);

downloadFile.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(success) {
        console.log("download complete: " + success.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Token XXXXXXX*"
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you jimish let me try that :)

Comment: when m trying to create  config.xml (/res/xml/config.xml)
it give me this error "Error in an XML file: aborting build."